# How should i view stack data of a specific address in GDB?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

Simple c source code to execute a program:

```
int main ( int argc , char **argv )                                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                            
        system ("XXXX");                                                                                                                           
        return 0;                                                                                                                                            
}
```

Now compile it and debug with gdb , and i tried to view what address of "XXX" actually represents by using `p` command , but got an void , am i doing it wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to examine a string located at address `0x40063c`, use the GDB `examine` command:

```
(gdb) x/s 0x40063c
```

Note that this data is *not* on the stack. You can find out where that data is with `info symbol` command:

```
(gdb) info sym 0x40063c
```

(this should print something like `symbol LC1 in .rodata of a.out`)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the $ character - it's part of assembly syntax, but not of gdb syntax.
And the "x" command is easier to use if you simply want to see the memory:

```
(gdb) p/s 0x40063c
```

You can also use p/x to show in hex format, and there are lots of other variations.